# smack message sent status

Tags: android, openfire, smack

I am using smack and openfire for create chat app in android .
for message status I have no problem with delivered and displayed message in other 
client (double check).
I will send a simple json message like bellow to sender:
 {"delivery":timestapmp}
 and parse it and double check messages with lower than timestamp that sent before.
the problem is about sent status (one check).
When i send message the server no response anything that message has sent .
is it possible in smack to send message with callback from server.
if possible and is it possible to send time server in callback response .
thanks .

Comment: which is the version of smack you are using

Comment: last version , 4.2

Comment: see I have answered for you

Comment: please check and let me know

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
private void acknowledgementFromServer(final Message message) throws StreamManagementException.StreamManagementNotEnabledException {
        if (connection != null && connection.isSmEnabled()) {
            connection.addStanzaIdAcknowledgedListener(message.getStanzaId(), new StanzaListener() {
                @Override
                public void processStanza(Stanza packet) throws SmackException.NotConnectedException, InterruptedException {

                        MessageAsyncTask task = new MessageAsyncTask(packet.getStanzaId(), MSG_STATUS_SENT);
                        task.execute();

                }
            });
        }
```

Hey you can do it like this.. call method every time you send message by passing that message as a parameter in above method

Note: Stream Management should be enabled for this to work, can be done like below:

```
DeliveryReceiptManager.setDefaultAutoReceiptMode(DeliveryReceiptManager.AutoReceiptMode.always);
        ProviderManager.addExtensionProvider(DeliveryReceipt.ELEMENT, DeliveryReceipt.NAMESPACE, new DeliveryReceipt.Provider());
        ProviderManager.addExtensionProvider(DeliveryReceiptRequest.ELEMENT, DeliveryReceipt.NAMESPACE, new DeliveryReceiptRequest.Provider());
```

Comment: can you please explain me how this is going to work so that i can also get to know this

Comment: What is `MessageAsyncTask `

Comment: that's my async task to update status of message to sqlite.. to be more clear its just to handle the response like u can have a method also in that place.. MessageAsyncTask is not related if you dont want to save your response

Comment: can you please tell me how are you getting status of message delivered in packet>

Comment: in this method `@Override
                public void processStanza(Stanza packet)`

Comment: it is not for message delivery, The question is how to get sent status, i.e, How to know that the message has been sent to server. Delivery Status is when the message is received by other user..

Comment: connection.addStanzaIdAcknowledgedListener(message.getStanzaId()...  if u check this line we are adding ack listener for every message we send by passing the packet id... @Override public void processStanza(Stanza packet) and here it receives same packet id if that message has receved by server

Comment: Then what is the use of `DeliveryReceiptManager`

Comment: what is this ? is this a Constant? `MSG_STATUS_SENT`

Comment: I got the question, but what is the use of `DeliveryReceiptManager`

Comment: http://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/ there you go its a link to smack's official doc where you can find explanation

Comment: I have gone through it, what I  am asking is they have not mentioned that it is acknowldgement from server : `Provides a mechanism to listen for packets that pass a specified filter. This allows event-style programming -- every time a new stanza(/packet) is found, the processStanza(Stanza) method will be called`

Comment: * Add a new Stanza ID acknowledged listener for the given ID.
     * <p>
     * The listener will be invoked if the stanza with the given ID was acknowledged by the server. It will
     * automatically be removed after the listener was run.
     
    Check this..

Comment: how to get the Message? like when I send the message using Chat class so how to get Message object

Comment: note: processStanza() this only denote that the message is send to xmpp server not the user. If the user is offline then also we will get the callback in processStanza()

Comment: This is great for finding out if a message is actually sent

Answer (score 2):

According to my knowledge I have got up to this Inteface : `ReceiptReceivedListener` which is in `smack 4.2`

below is how I have implemented this :

```
private ReceiptReceivedListener receiptReceivedListener;

/**
 * get DeliveryReceiptManager
 *
 * @return
 */
private DeliveryReceiptManager getDeliveryReceiptManager() {
    if (deliveryReceiptManager == null && getConnection() != null) {
        deliveryReceiptManager = DeliveryReceiptManager.getInstanceFor(getConnection());
    }
    return deliveryReceiptManager;
}
```

**add Listener**

```
getDeliveryReceiptManager().addReceiptReceivedListener(receiptReceivedListener);
```

**Received the call back**

```
receiptReceivedListener = new ReceiptReceivedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onReceiptReceived(Jid fromJid, Jid toJid, String receiptId, Stanza receipt) {
        //TODO : on recieved status of message delivery
    }
};
```

This will help you for sure

Below is the Interface for Smack 4.2 with full details :

```
/**
 * Callback invoked when a new receipt got received.
 * <p>
 * {@code receiptId} correspondents to the message ID, which can be obtained with
 * {@link org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Stanza#getStanzaId()}.
 * </p>
 * 
 * @param fromJid the jid that send this receipt
 * @param toJid the jid which received this receipt
 * @param receiptId the message ID of the stanza(/packet) which has been received and this receipt is for
 * @param receipt the receipt
 */
void onReceiptReceived(Jid fromJid, Jid toJid, String receiptId, Stanza receipt);
```

Comment: it seems this is client to client ,

Comment: I wana response from server ,when message sent

Comment: what does that mean:

Comment: which server ? you private or openfire?

Comment: server is openfire

Comment: So this is the callback from openfire itself

Comment: when i send message if user recieved message listner work,

Comment: but i want know message is received by server ,

Comment: How can I listen server if my message sended (Like one tick state in whatsapp) or how can I get error response if there is any error.

Comment: That you have to write your own logic using the ReceiptReceivedListener status that is not going to be the server part

Comment: thanks Raut Darpan for your help ,I wish the best for you

Comment: did it help? you